# Android VideoView playing HLS make the whole app no response

Tags: android, response, android-videoview

I have been using Android VideoView to play HLS(Http Live Stream), but if I pause the video for a while and continue to play it. the app will freeze, even if I click back button.

How can I finish VideoView thread without stopping the whole app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an inherent problem came with Android. There are two approaches to tackle this one.

1) Disable pause button of VideoView, a rewrite canPause() required.

2) Use ffmpeg library, for example Vitamio plugin. However, all these third libraries are not stable, may result in problems like video-audio out of synchronization, cannot drag and pause, etc defects.